# Sending SMS out from webapp, outgoing logged in phone sms app

Tags: android, web-applications

There are many Android gateways which does their job, synchronizing messages from the Android phone to the desktop. I am using DeskSMS and MightyText, and have started to look at AirDroid v2.

Now, the problem I need to solve is to send messages out from my webapp. I can't find a solution to send out messages from within my webapp so that auto generated messages will be sent out to our clients through the Android phone. The most important thing here is to log all outgoing sms in the native SMS app.

There is a [DeskSMS API](https://github.com/ClockworkMod/DeskSMS/wiki/DeskSMS-API) which I have absolutely no idea how to start using it, or can it solve my problem for that matter. Finally, if no one can recommend me any solution, how about a work around? E.g. copy and pasting the text to DeskSMS webapp and sending it on a click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm a bit late on this one.

If your webapp can send an email you can install PopMyPhone on your own Android phone and use this as an SMS gateway.

You can get PopMyPhone to send SMS messages to contacts upon receipt of an email. For example if you have a contact in your phone called Fred with a phone number of +447777777777 then sending an email to +447777777777@popmyphone.com will actually send an SMS to Fred containing the email body. The native SMS app will send the SMS messages and there will be a log. If you address your email to multiple PopMyPhone recipients they will each get an SMS

I hope this makes sense, you can get it here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.messagesphere.ui